# Voronoi diagram python

Tags: python, path-finding, voronoi

I am trying to make an Ai in **Tron Battle - Codingame**
And I was told that a **[Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)** would help to make my Ai better.
The only problem is my response time has to be under **100ms**

So this is what I need to do:

Get Voronoi diagram for all players including me
Using this I need to get the best direction to have the most open squares/cells on the board closest to me.

I have tried to use **pathfinding** to get the closest points but that is super extra slow and isn't as good.

*What would be the fastest but simplest way to do this without using outside libraries like scipy and numpy??*

Comment: A question should be self contained; include a description of what a voroni diagram is. Also show wha you have tried so far rather than just asking for an answer.